# Do I have to pop the error code pushed to stack by certain exceptions before returning from the interrupt handler?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, interrupt, osdev

I have loaded an idt table with 256 entries, all pointing to similar handlers:

- for exceptions 8 and 10-14, push the exception number (these exceptions push an error code automatically)
- for the others, push a "dummy" error code and the exception number;
- then jump to a common handler

So when the common handler enters, the stack is properly aligned and contains the exception/interrupt number, error code (which may just be a dummy), eflags, cs and eip.

My question regards returning from the interrupt handler. I use `iret` to return after taking out the exception number and the error code from the stack, but this doesn't work for exception nr 8; if I leave the error code on the stack, then it returns fine!

Questions:

- do I have to leave the error code on the stack for exceptions that put the error code there? If so, how does `iret` determine whether it has to pop an error code or not?
- as soon as I enable interrupts I always get exception 8 (double fault), but then everything runs fine (I'm developing a hobby OS). Is this normal behavior or do I have a bug somewhere?

Comment: Also, pointers to the intel manuals would be most welcome :) I haven't found anything regarding these problems there yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the CPU pushed an error code automatically, the handler ***must*** pop it before the `iret`.  The `iret` instruction doesn't know where you're coming from, if it's a fault, a trap or an external interrupt.  It always does the same, and it assumes that there's no error code on the stack.

Quoting from the SDM (Software Developer's Manual), Volume 3, Chapter 5, section 5.13 titled Error Code:

> The error code is pushed on the stack
>   as a doubleword or word (depending on
>   the default interrupt, trap, or task
>   gate size). To keep the stack aligned
>   for doubleword pushes, the upper half
>   of the error code is reserved. Note
>   that the error code is not popped when
>   the IRET instruction is executed to
>   return from an exception handler, so
>   the handler must remove the error code
>   before executing a return.

You can find the [IA-32 Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) [here](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/): http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Volume 3 part 1, chapter 5, describes exception and interrupt handling.  Volume 2 part 1 has the spec for the `iret` instruction.

Comment: I somehow missed that paragraph :) So now I know this is a bug in my code. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with "double faults" as soon as I enabled interrupts.  Well, they *looked* like double faults, but they really were timer interrupts!

Double faults are interrupt number `8`.

Unfortunately, a default PIC configuration signals timer interrupts as interrupt number `(DEFAULT_PIC_BASE + TIMER_OFFSET)` = `(8 + 0)` = `8`.

Masking out all my PIC interrupts (until I was ready to properly configure the PIC) silenced these double-fault-lookalike timer interrupts.

(PICs require the CPU to acknowledge interrupts before they produce the next one.  Since your code wasn't acknowledging the initial timer interrupt, the PIC never gave you any more!  That's why you only got one, rather than the zillion one might have expected.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [small x86 OS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osamos) a while back. Take a look at the file [isr.asm](http://osamos.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/osamos/AMOS/src/kernel/isr.asm?view=markup) in the cvs repository.

Notice how we set up the handlers, most push a dummy dword onto the stack to account for the few handlers that automatically get an error code pushed. Then when we return via an iret we can always assume 2 dwords on the stack irrespective of the interrupt and perform an add esp, 8 before the iret to clean things up nicely.

That should answer your first question.

As for your second question: A double fault when you enable interrupts, ...hmmm could be a problem with paging if you haven't set it up correctly. Could be a million other thing too :)

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the reply :) I don't have paging enabled and I only have 3 valid entries in the GDT (for code and data in ring 0, and another to use in real-mode). I'm usually in protected-mode but I go back to real-mode to use some BIOS routines (mostly reading from the disk). Any clues? :)

Comment: Sorry can't think of anything off hand, maybe switching back to real mode causes problems

Comment: Link to your OS is dead, maybe you have a GitHub version? I'm making a collection of educational OSes.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to leave the error code on the stack for exceptions that put the error code there?

As others mentioned, you have to do either:

```
pop %eax
/* Do something with %eax */
iret
```

Or if you want to ignore the error code:

```
add $4, %esp
iret
```

If you don't, `iret` will interpret the error code as the new CS, and you are likely to get a general protection fault as mentioned at: [Why does iret from a page fault handler generate interrupt 13 (general protection fault) and error code 0x18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581224/why-does-iret-from-a-page-fault-handler-generate-interrupt-13-general-protectio)

[Minimal Working this page handler](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/1f6af9021283dc01f2247efbb6aa9217363fbf07/page_fault.S#L47) that I've created to illustrate this. Try commenting out the `pop` and see it blow up.

Compare the above with a [Division error exception](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/1f6af9021283dc01f2247efbb6aa9217363fbf07/idt_zero_divide.S#L33) which does not to pop the stack.

Note that if you do simply `int $14`, no extra byte gets pushed: this only happens on the actual exception.

[Intel Manual Volume 3 System Programming Guide - 325384-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081259/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) Table 6-1. "Protected-Mode Exceptions and Interrupts" column "Error Code" contains the list of interrupts that push the error code or not.

38.9.2.2 "Page Fault Error Codes" explains what the error means.

A neat way to deal with this is to push a dummy error code `0` on the stack for the interrupts that don't do this to make things uniform. James Molloy's tutorial [does exactly that](https://github.com/cirosantilli/jamesmolloy-kernel-development-tutorials/blob/631106c09e02bae9b2da21999224bb2e2d5c4411/6_paging/interrupt.asm#L38).

The Linux kernel 4.2 seems to do something similar. Under [arch/x86/entry/entry64.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.2/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L1078) it models interrupts with `has_error_code`:

```
trace_idtentry page_fault do_page_fault has_error_code=1
```

and then uses it on the same file as:

```
.ifeq \has_error_code
pushq $-1 /* ORIG_RAX: no syscall to restart */
.endif
```

which does the push when `has_error_code=0`.

Comment: Most OSes would set up their IDT so `int $14` or `int $0` from user-space isn't allowed.  i.e. it doesn't enter the same exception handler as an actual #PF or #DE, instead it will cause a #GP.  This allows exception-handlers to assume an error code is present or not as appropriate, and doesn't let user-space fake things.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Yes, specifically the IDT in such OSes would have entries for those interrupts with a Descriptor Privilege Level (DPL) set to 0 (Ring 0) rather than set to 3 (Ring3). If the Current Privilege Level (CPL) is less than the DPL of the interrupt it is allowed otherwise a #GP. This particular check doesn't apply to external interrupts.

Answer (score -1):

In 64 bit mode the interrupt stack is aligned on a 16 byte boundary. So, regardless as to whether the vector was called by an int instruction, an exception, a hardware interrupt, or has no error code, a possible error code can be popped simply by setting the least significant bits of the stack pointer.

The following code gives a consistent, 16 byte aligned stack:

```
    push 1
    push 0
    and rsp, -8  ; Align Stack

L1: ...

    test [rsp+8], 1
    jz L2

    ... ; Error code present

    jmp L3

L2: ... ; Error code absent

L3: ...

    add rsp, 24
    retiq
```

| Stack Before |  |
| --- | --- |
| ff8: ss | ff8: ss |
| ff0: rsp | ff0: rsp |
| fe8: rflags | fe8: rflags |
| fe0: cs | fe0: cs |
| fd8: rip <= rsp | fd8: rip |
|  | fd0: Error Code <= rsp |

| Stack At L1 |  |
| --- | --- |
| ff8: ss | ff8: ss |
| ff0: rsp | ff0: rsp |
| fe8: rflags | fe8: rflags |
| fe0: cs | fe0: cs |
| fd8: rip | fd8: rip |
| fd0: 1 | fd0: Error Code |
| fc8: 0 | fc8: 1 |
| fc0: xxxx <= rsp | fc0: 0 <= rsp |

For the case where no there is no privilege level change,  the CPU will align the stack on a 16 byte boundary before pushing the ss.  Where there is a privilege level change (or the IST is used) simply ensure that the entries in the TSS are 16 byte aligned.  To return,  simply pop off the garbage or error code and execute iretq.

For more information see sections 6.14.2 and 7.7 in the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual - Volume 3A" available [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html).

Comment: You might want to correct these: "16 **bit** aligned stack", "privil**a**ge level", and "execute retiq". (16-byte aligned stack, privilege level, execute `iretq`)

Comment: The stack is aligned after the interrupt occurs but before the return values are pushed in all cases if the tss entries are aligned (aligned on 16 byte boundary) as explained in the second paragraph.

Answer (score -2):

In 64 bit mode the interrupt stack is aligned on a 16 byte boundary.  So, regardless as to whether the vector was called by an int instruction, an exception, a hardware interrupt, or has no error code, a possible error code can be popped simply by setting the least significant bit of the stack pointer.

Comment: The stack doesn't have to be 16 byte aligned when an interrupt occurs (or if a priv level change the SS0:ESP0 in the TSS structure doesn't have to be 16 byte aligned although OS developers often have that kind of alignment). In 64-bit mode the error is a 64-bit value pushed on the stack so setting the low bit of the stack pointer isn't going to do what you think it will do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).